# Width="600" on parent table not respected in Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I've built a responsive email which works in the majority of email clients

However in Outlook the parent table that makes the content 600 wide is not being respected - resulting in a broken layout.
[>Image of broken email in outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SrYG.png)

I'm really stuck . Does anyone know why this might be happening?

JS Fiddle of my code --> https://jsfiddle.net/2m05tzf5/

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<td>
<center>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td>
<![endif]-->
<table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;" class="emailwrapto100pc" id="content">
```

Comment: Have you tried CSS instead of HTML attributes?

Comment: Thank you @Justinas - so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using CSS `table{table-layout: fixed; width: 600px;}`. Keep in mind that not all attributes and CSS rules are supported in all e-mail parsers